# Ubuntu 12.04.5 Server No Internet from ethernet connection at work

Tags: networking, server, internet

I am using Ubuntu Server 12.04.5

I am using an ethernet connection that connects to my company's intranet.

All the other computers I work with are connected to an AD domain and the Ubuntu server is not connected to the domain.

Should I be able to connect to the internet even though this server is not connected to the domain?

Comment: It really depends on your network to internet connection, such as any proxies, firewalls and authentication used, very hard to provide an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As the comment above states, I may have not provided enough information to answer the question.

That said, to fix my problem the network team at my workplace had to mark my MAC address for entry into the specific vlan used.